# Prevent lock of windows detecting user idle time

Tags: windows, terminal-services

I work in a Windows Terminal Server enviroment where if you left the computer for a while, windows lock the session and terminal is power off.

What i need is the code needed to send a message to Windows for it to believe the user is in front of the PC (mouse or keyboard activity).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you run mstsc with the /console parameter? This will get you in console mode and wont time out.  The screen will lock with the normal timeout, but you wont get disconnected.  Be careful though, as anyone else trying to get into the console will then need to log you out in order to get on.

Answer (score 0):

You can control session disconnect (connection is closed but session remains open and can be reconnected) and reset (connection and session are closed) timeouts via local or group policy.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure screen saver on remote server and local PC is set to some ridiculous amount like 960 minutes (8 hours).  Open a command prompt on the remote server. Tape the enter key down on your local keyboard.  The system will interpret this as user activity.  It won't affect performance or mess anything up.  Any your boss will think you're working while you're off playing XBOX360, or watching a movie, or smooching with a co-worker in the emergency stairwell.